# How do I do cross-platform (web and native) URL routing with React Router 4?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm starting a project that I'm hoping to make mostly cross-platform with [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web).

I'm using this react-native starter template here: https://github.com/react-everywhere/re-start

And the only thing I'm struggling to get working is URL routing.

in my index.js, I have my App component like so:

```
class App extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/about' component={AboutScreenComponent}/>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={TopLevelComponent}/>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

Then I just wanted to test a link, so I added a `<Link to="/about"><Text>Link to About</Text</Link>` inside of `TopLevelComponent`.

On web, it works just as expected.  In the Android emulator, clicking the link doesn't do anything.

The docs on this functionality are light.  I know I need to do something with [DeepLinking](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/api/DeepLinking) but I'm just not sure exactly what I need to do.  My understanding is I need to modify the android manifest file to allow URL routing, but I didn't have much luck with that either.

How can I enable URL routing with react-router-native on android if my dev server is localhost:3000?

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Platform } from 'react-native'

let Router
if (Platform.OS === 'web') {
  Router = require('react-router-dom').BrowserRouter
} else {
  Router = require('react-router-native').NativeRouter
}
```

Comment: According to webpack+babel's error message when I tried this: "'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level"

Answer (score 1):

My feeling is that the shared cross platform components should mainly just be your pure view components. The outer layers of the app, like routing, should use a library most appropriate for the platform, i.e. react-router for web, and react-navigation or similar for native. Perhaps in the future we can have a truly unified code base, but for now it doesn't feel like the technology is ready ...